# Warning: React does not recognize the `PaperComponent` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I have simple modal using material ui 'Modal', i want to make it draggable, so user could move modal whereever they want simply by dragging, so i used 'Draggable' from react draggable, but i'm getting this error: Warning: React does not recognize the `PaperComponent` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `papercomponent` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

what am i doing wrong ?

codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/draggabledialog-material-demo-forked-srw9yn?file=/demo.js

code:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { Modal, Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Close } from "@material-ui/icons";

import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";

export default function DraggableDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  function PaperComponent(props) {
    return (
      <Draggable
        handle="#draggable-dialog-title"
        cancel={'[class*="MuiDialogContent-root"]'}
      >
        <Paper {...props} />
      </Draggable>
    );
  }

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open draggable dialog
      </Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
        // aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
      >
        <div>
          <form
            style={{
              width: "360px",
              color: "white",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              backgroundColor: "#1E2328"
            }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "black",
                margin: "0",
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "center",
                height: "56px",
                width: "360px",
                color: "white",
                justifyContent: "space-between"
              }}
              m={2}
            >
              <Box
                style={{
                  color: "#E9ECEC",
                  fontSize: "21px"
                }}
              >
                Countries{" "}
              </Box>
              <button
                style={{ color: "white" }}
                onClick={handleClose}
                aria-label="close-settings-popup"
              >
                <Close />
              </button>
            </div>
            <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
              <div>
                Country Name
                <p>Germany</p>
                <p>France</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `component={PaperComponent}` instead of `PaperComponent={PaperComponent}`?

Comment: @NicholasTower examples used 'PaperComponent' dont know maybe im using it wrong, simply i want to make that modal draggable

Comment: `examples used 'PaperComponent' ` Those examples appear to be making a mistake. The Modal component is not expecting a prop named "PaperComponent", but it does expect one named "component". [See documentation for Modal](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/)

Comment: yes you seem to be right, then what should i do to make Modal component draggable ?

Comment: Not sure... i tried fiddling with the code to use `component={PaperComponent}`, and that doesn't seem to work either :(

Comment: @NicholasTower i made it draggable but there is one problem, if you drag modal you can drag whole thing which i dont want (i dont want to drag what is behind modal, i want to drag just the modal) https://codesandbox.io/s/draggabledialog-material-demo-forked-v3jn7f?file=/demo.js

Comment: Move the draggable inside the modal: https://codesandbox.io/s/draggabledialog-material-demo-forked-8nh49n?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0):

#### Modal component does not recognize PaperComponent that you passing to it as prop,

**if you only want modal to be draggable modify your code like so:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { Modal, Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Close } from "@material-ui/icons";

import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";

export default function DraggableDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open draggable dialog
      </Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        // aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
      >
       <Draggable>
        <div>
          <form
            style={{
              width: "360px",
              color: "white",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              backgroundColor: "#1E2328"
            }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "black",
                margin: "0",
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "center",
                height: "56px",
                width: "360px",
                color: "white",
                justifyContent: "space-between"
              }}
              m={2}
            >
              <Box
                style={{
                  color: "#E9ECEC",
                  fontSize: "21px"
                }}
              >
                Countries{" "}
              </Box>
              <button
                style={{ color: "white" }}
                onClick={handleClose}
                aria-label="close-settings-popup"
              >
                <Close />
              </button>
            </div>
            <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
              <div>
                Country Name
                <p>Germany</p>
                <p>France</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Draggable>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/draggabledialog-material-demo-forked-sx2npc?file=/demo.js